# Pandas - exception handling converting hex to inr

Tags: pandas, exception, error-handling, hex, apply

Hello everyone my first post on stackoverflow so please be gentle :)

I have a Pandas Dataframe with several columns, one of which includes hex values which I need to convert back to decimal. I have been getting the error message:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: ''`

and have worked out that this is because I have empty values in my column. To illustrate with a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['0000000000000000000000000000000000000156a','0C3'], columns=['Col1'])
res = df['Col1'].apply(int, base=16)
print(res)
```

gives me the following (which is working and correct so far):

```
Output:
0    5482
1     195
Name: Col1, dtype: int64
```

However, if I then add in an empty value into my dataset (and my full dataset has plenty) as below then I get the above ValueError:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['0000000000000000000000000000000000000156a','0C3', ''], columns=['Col1'])
```

I understand why this is but then am trying to use error handling solutions that I have found on other question threads e.g.

```
res = df['Col1'].apply(lambda x: int(x, 16) if str(x).isdigit() else None)
```

This handles the error but the output is not correct and gives all 3 values as None as below:

```
Output:
0    None
1    None
2    None
Name: Col1, dtype: object
```

I am sure I am making a basic error here but have been working on this for 2 hours and cannot sort it out. I have tried other things such as passing extra arguments into the .apply() but each time this errors. Thanks for taking a look.

EDIT:
I have found a workaround but it does not feel especially elegant. I can get the desired output by using the replace method:

```py
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].replace('', '0')
res = df['Col1'].apply(int, base=16)
```

but is there a more elegant more pythonic way of achieving this result?

Comment: Neither of your first two are actually all digits which is what `str.isdigit` checks... (there's letters in there as well...)

Comment: Thanks Jon. These are base 16 values so intent to have letters in them. I have solved the issue by replacing ```str.isdigit``` with ```str.isalnum```. Pointing out the issue with ```str.isdigit``` helped enormously - thank you.

Comment: That's what I was hinting at... just be wary that `str.isalnum` will be true for all letters not just valid hex digits...